# Enabling/Desabling Custom Execution Filters in Symfony 1.4.11?

Tags: symfony1, action-filter

I've created a custom Symfony execution filter to manage the integrity of a POST request by extending the sfFilter class. The filter works OK but some times I need to disable it and the fact is the parameter condition specified in the filter definition in filters.yml file(see below) is not working.

```
# filters.yml

rendering: ~
security:  ~
SSL:
  class: SSLFilter
  condition: %APP_ENABLE_SSLFILTER%

integrity:
  class:  IntegrityFilter
  param:
    integrity_header:   x-integrity-cnonce
    condition:  %APP_ENABLE_INTEGRITYCHECK%

cache:     ~
execution: ~
```

As you can see the condition for the IntegrityFilter requires the configuration entry ENABLE_INTEGRITYCHECK to be ON in the app.yml file to execute the filter.

```
# app.yml
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    algorithm_callable:   md5
    success_signout_url:  /
    success_signin_url:   /
  enable_sslfilter: off
  # Enables de IntegrityFilter check
  enable_integritycheck: off
```

Well the thing is that's not working and it's becoming since I use a script to enable/disable some settings along with other tasks and that one isn't disabling. The funny thing is that enabling/disabling works fine for the the SSL Filter shown in both YAML files. Any ideas...?

Comment: `contidion: %APP_ENABLE_SSLFILTER%` is misspelled, should be `condition: %APP_ENABLE_SSLFILTER%`

Comment: After your script enables/disables settings, does it also clear cache?

Comment: sorry about the "contidion"..it was a typo. And yes the script also clears the cache. I've consulted other colleagues about this issue and they told me the same: the condition doesn't work..even the guy who implemented the SSLFilter told me he had to harcoded the condition check by asking directly to sfConfig.